# Google Apps Script: Calendar .getEvents imports events in wrong timezone

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script, timezone

Calendar.getEvents works only in PDT time zone not possible to retrieve events in my GMT+02.00 (Europe/Warsaw, CEST) zone.
I'am newbie in programming JS and GAS but it's looks like some issue and maybe there is some walkaround for my problem?
Utilities.formatDate also treat new Date() as PDT time zone.
All my apps works in same time zone.
Forgive for my language, it's not my native.

---

code sample:

```
function date () {
var dateS = new Date(2015,3,20);
var dateE = new Date();
  Logger.log("Start :", dateS);
  Logger.log("Stop :", dateE);
 var timeZone = Session.getScriptTimeZone();
 var spr = CalendarApp.setTimeZone(timeZone);
 var rps = SpreadsheetApp.getActive()
                         .setSpreadsheetTimeZone(timeZone);
 var cal = CalendarApp.getCalendarsByName("Norske hellig- og merkedager");
 var week = Utilities.formatDate(dateS, timeZone, "ww");  
  Logger.log("Week nr:", week);
  var events = cal[0].getEvents(dateS, dateE);
  for (i=1; i < events.length; i++) 
  {
    Logger.log(events[i]);
    }
}
```

return:

```
[15-04-26 13:49:48:630 CEST] Logger.log([Start :, [Mon Apr 20 00:00:00 GMT+02:00 2015]]) [0 s]
[15-04-26 13:49:48:630 CEST] Logger.log([Stop :, [Sun Apr 26 13:49:48 GMT+02:00 2015]]) [0 s]
[15-04-26 13:49:48:630 CEST] Session.getScriptTimeZone() [0 s]
[15-04-26 13:49:49:166 CEST] CalendarApp.setTimeZone([Europe/Warsaw]) [0,535 s]
[15-04-26 13:49:49:166 CEST] SpreadsheetApp.getActive() [0 s]
[15-04-26 13:49:49:189 CEST] Spreadsheet.setSpreadsheetTimeZone([Europe/Warsaw]) [0,022 s]
[15-04-26 13:49:49:415 CEST] CalendarApp.getCalendarsByName([Norske hellig- og merkedager]) [0,225 s]
[15-04-26 13:49:49:416 CEST] Utilities.formatDate([Sun Apr 19 15:00:00 PDT 2015, Europe/Warsaw, ww]) [0 s]
[15-04-26 13:49:49:416 CEST] Logger.log([Week nr:, [17]]) [0 s]
[15-04-26 13:49:49:647 CEST] Calendar.getEvents([Sun Apr 19 15:00:00 PDT 2015, Sun Apr 26 04:49:48 PDT 2015]) [0,23 s]
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't rely on values displayed in the execution transcript (and sometimes in the Logger as well, at least in the past... not sure now), don't forget this code is executed on Google's servers wich are based in California and use a Pacific time zone as a standard ;-)
but if you use `Utilities.formatDate` correctly you'll get the right values.

Look at the Logger result after trying this code adapted from yours :

```
function date () {
  var dateS = new Date(2015,3,20);
  var dateE = new Date();
  Logger.log("Start :", dateS);
  Logger.log("Stop :", dateE);
  var timeZone = Session.getScriptTimeZone();
  Logger.log(timeZone);
  var spr = CalendarApp.setTimeZone(timeZone);
  var rps = SpreadsheetApp.getActive()
  .setSpreadsheetTimeZone(timeZone);
  var cal = CalendarApp.getCalendarsByName("test_agenda")[0];// I changed to a calendar I own for my test
  cal.createEventFromDescription('test event, today 9AM');// create a dummy event for test purpose
  var week = Utilities.formatDate(dateS, timeZone, "ww");  
  Logger.log("Week nr:", week);
  var events = cal.getEvents(dateS, dateE);
  for (i=1; i < events.length; i++) 
  {
    Logger.log(Utilities.formatDate(events[i].getStartTime(),timeZone,"yyyy/MM/dd @ HH:mm"));
  }
}
```

[image]

The date object is right but it shows up differently in the execution transcript, **you can ignore this difference**.
The `Utilities.formatDate` method allows for correct display.

[image]

Comment: Serge I think this can be controlled in the script properties : timezone settings

Comment: Thanks mate. Everything is allright. It was my bad I was looking mistake on the other side ;) I had problem with one data object and that make mess in my thinking. Thanks one more time :)

Comment: @Zig : do you mean the tz in logger ? that probably explains why I had issues before (a couple of years ago maybe ?) and not anymore... but I wasn't sure. thx for the info. I guess the execution transcript will always be in PDT right ?

Comment: Not sure. A bunch of formatting stuff depends on that setting.